# Java Swing Application L&F in KDE environment (Red Hat Linux)

Tags: java, swing

My Java Swing application is not showing system look and feel (KDE) while running on Red Hat Linux. It is showing the default (and also ugly) Java look and feel when I switch to KDE view in Red Hat. It is showing the system look and feel when I am using GNOME view in Red Hat. I am using the following code to set look and feel. Can anyone throw some light as to what could be the problem?

```
setApplicationLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

private     void    setApplicationLookAndFeel (String LookAndFeel) {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(LookAndFeel);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler? Sun Java?

Comment: openJDK - 1.6 on Eclipse Galileo

Answer (score 0):

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myContainer);
```

`Container` I meaning [JFrame, JDialog or JWindow](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)

Comment: Well, that would be the obviously easier solution, but I think since the JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true) is called, the update should automatically happend

Comment: I changed compiler to jre-1.6.27 from Oracle site but still the problem remained. I also tried updating the component tree hierarchy. But then as per - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209731/how-do-i-force-get-to-use-gtklookandfeel-in-java-on-kde

Comment: I tried to force it to take GTK L&F by changing to                  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel"). And now the problem is that - though the L&F has changed to KDE L&F but all the text characters have lost their anti-aliased property. Not to mention that the LAF is also hard coded! Mess.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likey the fault of the openjdk. I've had innumerable problems with openjdk on linux/debian, to the point where I now instinctively remove it and install Oracle JDK. Try that one.